# Odd printing issue in C

Tags: c

I was helping a student programmer with a simple program and came across a perplexing issue.
The output was supposed to look like this:

```
###########
##  cat  ##
###########
```

But it instead came out like this:

```
################
##  catr+]U  ##
################
```

The strange thing about it wasn't necessarily the output itself, but rather the fact that the issue became resolved when I put some filler code at the beginning of main. For instance, main initially looked like this:

```
int main() {
    char s[] = {'c','a','t'};
    frameText(s);
}
```

And the output came out wrong. However, I changed it to look like this:

```
int main() {
    int k = 0;
    k++;
    k++;
    printf("%d I am confused\n", k);
    char s[] = {'c','a','t'};
    frameText(s);
}
```

And the issue was fixed. I've never encountered anything like this before and I cannot figure out what happened.
Here's the full program, in case that helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void frameText( char s[] ) {
    int len;
    len = strlen(s);
    s[len] = '\0';

    for (int k = 0; k < len + 7; k++) {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("##  %s  ##\n",s);

    for (int k = 0; k < len + 7; k++) {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int k = 0;
    k++;
    k++;
    printf("%d I am confused\n", k);
    char s[] = {'c','a','t'};
    frameText(s);
}
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate If the array is valid, `s[len] = '\0';` is meaningless but not out-of-range access because there should already be a null character there.

Answer (score 3):

Strings in C are terminated by null-character `'\0'`, so you must add that to your array.

Use

```
    char s[] = {'c','a','t','\0'};
```

or

```
    char s[] = "cat";
```

instead of

```
    char s[] = {'c','a','t'};
```

Another way is specifying the length to print explicitly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void frameText( char s[], int len ) {

    for (int k = 0; k < len + 8; k++) {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("##  %.*s  ##\n",len,s);

    for (int k = 0; k < len + 8; k++) {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int k = 0;
    k++;
    k++;
    printf("%d I am confused\n", k);
    char s[] = {'c','a','t'};
    frameText(s, sizeof(s));
}
```

Also your printing of `#` in the upper and lower line was 1 character less than expected. I also fixed that in the "another way".